# Comentar una opción y añadir despues la nueva, si no existe la opción añadirla

Tags: bash, sed

Quiero modificar archivos de configuración pero sin perder la opción que había antes. 
Para ello utilizo el comando sed para añadir y comentar.
También utilizo grep para chequear si la opción no existe, añadirla.

Mi problema viene cuando le paso dos veces el script que me replica las opciones.

```
## comentar linea
sudo sed -i 's/^secure-file-priv/#secure-file-priv/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf 
## inserta despues
sudo sed -i '/^#secure-file-priv/a secure-file-priv=/tmp/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf 

## si no encuentra la linea la añade
grep -q secure-file-priv /etc/mysql/my.cnf  2> /dev/null || 
    echo -e '######################### \nsecure-file-priv=/tmp/' >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

La salida si lo ejecuto dos veces es esta:

```
#secure-file-priv=/tmp/ 
secure-file-priv=/tmp/
#secure-file-priv=/tmp/ 
secure-file-priv=/tmp/
```

Me gustaría saber alguna forma de hacer esto correctamente en Bash.

El fichero original podría ser:

```
opcion1=opt1
secure-file-priv=/tmp/
opcion2=opt2
```

y al pasar el script el resultado fuera este

```
opcion1=opt1
#secure-file-priv=/tmp/
secure-file-priv=/tmp/rutanueva
opcion2=opt2
```

Y si lo volviera a pasar que me comente el que no está comentado tal que así:

```
opcion1=opt1
#secure-file-priv=/tmp/
#secure-file-priv=/tmp/rutanueva
secure-file-priv=/newpath/
opcion2=opt2
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo es el fichero original y cómo quieres que sea al final?

Comment: He puesto un ejemplo de lo que busco. Si no queda claro lo volveré a editar.

Comment: Está perfecto ahora, Takyo. Contesté ahora, no tuve tiempo ante de hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta sería una solución.

Lo primero que se hace es buscar la línea donde está el término a reemplazar, luego de ellos si no existe se agrega más si existe se reemplaza, usando `sed` para cambiar sobre la línea donde está el texto y posteriormente. En la línea siguiente de donde se hizo el reemplazo, se inserta la nueva variable dejando las anteriores comentadas.

### archivo.txt

```
opcion1=opt1
opcion2=opt2
secure-file-priv=/tmp/
```

### script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ARCHIVO=archivo.txt
TEXTO="secure-file-priv=test"

# Linea donde se encuentra el ultimo parametro sin comentar
LINEA=$(grep -n "^secure-file-priv" $ARCHIVO | tail -1 | cut -f1 -d':')

# Si no existe la linea se agrega
if [ -z "$LINEA" ] ; then
    echo "El parametro NO existe, se agregara"
    echo -e '######################### \nsecure-file-priv=/tmp/' >> $ARCHIVO
fi

# Linea posterior
SIGUIENTE_LINEA=$(($LINEA+1))

# Realizamos el reemplazo de la linea
sed -i "$LINEA s/^secure-file-priv/#secure-file-priv/g" $ARCHIVO 
sed -i ''" $SIGUIENTE_LINEA "' i '" $TEXTO "'' $ARCHIVO
```

**Primera Ejecución:**

> cat archivo.txt

```
opcion1=opt1
opcion2=opt2
secure-file-priv=/tmp/
```

**Segunda Ejecución:**

> cat archivo.txt

```
opcion1=opt1
opcion2=opt2
#secure-file-priv=/tmp/ 
secure-file-priv=test
```

**Tercera Ejecución:**

> cat archivo.txt

```
opcion1=opt1
opcion2=opt2
#secure-file-priv=/tmp/ 
#secure-file-priv=test 
secure-file-priv=test
```

Y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Interesante respuesta. Probablemente podrías hacer `grep -n "^secure-..." "$archivo"` para coger aquella línea no comentada, que es la que quiere. Por otra parte, si solamente quieres modificar una línea en particular, `sed '/patrón/s/busca/reemplaza/' fichero` debería ser suficiente. En este caso, algo así como `sed -r '/^secure-file-priv/s/^([^=])(.*)/#\1\2\n\1="hola"/' fichero`.

Answer (score 2):

Para diseccionar (*parsear*) un fichero, creo que `sed` no acaba de ser una buena herramienta porque rápidamente caes en expresiones regulares y cosas difíciles de mantener.

Aunque no es mucho mejor, creo que `awk` puede proveerte de mejores herramientas, a la vez que más ajustables.

¿Qué te parece lo siguiente `sc.awk`?

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}
$1 == opt {print "#"$0; print $1,"nuevo_valor"; next}
1
```

Que se ejecuta con:

```
awk -v opt="secure-file-priv" -v nuevo_valor="/tmp/rutanueva" -f sc.wk fichero
```

Esto hace tres cosas:

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}`
  Define `=` como separador de campos, tanto de entrada como de salida.
- `$1 == opt {print "#"$0; print $1, nuevo_valor; next}`
  Mira si el primer campo (el que hay hasta el símbolo "=") coincide con el parámetro dado `opt`. Si es así, imprime la línea actual con un "#" delante. A continuación, vuelve a escribir una línea junto con el nuevo valor dado. Después llama a `next` para dejar de procesar la línea actual.
- `1`
  Esto es una manera idiomática de hacer que `awk` escriba la línea actual sin mayores rodeos. Esto es así porque cualquier acción cierta desencadena la ejecución de `{print $0}`, que es lo que precisamente escribe la línea actual.

En cuanto al uso de `-v par="valor"` es la manera de pasar valores a variables de `awk`.

Veámoslo en acción dado el siguiente fichero:

```
$ cat fichero
opcion1=opt1
secure-file-priv=/tmp/
opcion2=opt2
```

Ejecutando el script `sc.awk`:

```
$ awk -v opt="secure-file-priv" -v nuevo_valor="/tmp/rutanueva" -f sc.wk fichero
opcion1=opt1
#secure-file-priv=/tmp/
secure-file-priv=/tmp/rutanueva
opcion2=opt2
```

O en forma de una sola línea:

```
$ awk -v opt="secure-file-priv" -v nuevo_valor="/tmp/rutanueva" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1 == opt {print "#"$0; print $1, nuevo_valor;next}1' fichero
opcion1=opt1
#secure-file-priv=/tmp/
secure-file-priv=/tmp/rutanueva
opcion2=opt2
```

---

Como siempre, si modificas un archivo sensible, haz una copia:

```
cp fichero fichero.20160210.bk
awk '...' fichero > fichero_tmp && mv fichero_tmp fichero
```